# Checking filenames in upload in R Shiny

Tags: r, validation, file-upload, shiny, filenames

Good afternoon.
I want to check in R shiny after uploading 2 files if one part of the filename is identical or not.
I have done this

```
data <- reactive({
    inFile=input$bam
    #str(inFile)
    clean_file_1=str_extract_all(inFile, regex("[0-9]{3}[:punct:][0-9]{5}[:punct:][A-Z]{3}[0-9]{8}"))[[1]]
    clean_file_2=str_extract_all(inFile, regex("[0-9]{3}[:punct:][0-9]{5}[:punct:][A-Z]{3}[0-9]{8}"))[[2]]
    #a = clean_file_1 == clean_file_2
    
    if (clean_file_1 == clean_file_2){
      return(inFile)
    } else {
      print("Error message by Adam")
    }
    #validate(need(clean_file_1 == clean_file_2, print("Please upload the same Dna number pool1+pool2"))
    
    
    
  })
```

Regex and comparison are correct when I checked out of shiny.
The error message in Shiny is the following

```
Warning: Error in if: the argument is of length zero
```

When I try with validate does not accept the comparison symbol

The target is that if the 2 uploaded files have a small part of filenames identical to proceed the app if are not to prompt an error message suggesting to the user to be careful of what files he uploaded.
Thank you

Comment: Your code is not reproducible, but I can imagine the error comes on app starts, because you haven't uploaded anything but the reactive starts to run and `input$bam` is NULL and this is what happens when you use NULL in `if`. You may want to add `req(input$bam)` as the first line inside your reactive.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The issue starts when I upload the 2 files. I search and I have added isTRUE(value1==value2) in the if statement.No error.....but still don't read the two files. When I have checked also with ifelse(isTRUE(clean_file_1 == clean_file_2), print("no"), inFile)    then if returns inFile appears the filename only of the one from two files

Comment: Can you provide `ui` and `server` code required for the question to be completely reproducible along with necessary data if required?

Comment: Good day sir and thank you for the answer.  Unfortunately, more info is sensitive data. But I tried many alternatives. The point is that I checked the output. When I print the output of data() returns the filenames. When I use those filenames from data() as input to other functions returns NULL. maybe I should change the form. The strange thing for me is when I try out of the Shiny working everything perfectly but when I insert to the Shiny app presenting this error....